# Jhipster login / authentication in mobile app

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, session-cookies, jhipster, csrf-protection

How to get a **session cookie** and the **CSRF token** from **jhipster** then use them in your calls to the API from mobile app.
I am using HTTP session authentication.

JHipster configuration, a **.yo-rc.json file** generated in the root folder

```
{
"generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
"baseName": "vconnect",
"packageName": "com.zenfact.vconnect",
"packageFolder": "com/zenfact/vconnect",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "session",
"hibernateCache": "ehcache",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "no",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSocialSignIn": false,
"rememberMeKey": "559bbe3167552d040ba24d16506d389a7ba851c3",
"useSass": false,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
"gatling"
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
"en",
"zh-cn",
"fr",
"hi",
"ja"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any mobile experience but cookies are known to be difficult with mobile. I'd recommend using jhipster's Oauth2 option instead. Then you just need to get an access token and add the header "Authorization: Bearer " to your api calls.

Comment: Thank you @sdoxsee. I am new to jhipster so I created the with http session but after reading your answer I did a little digging it seems Oauth2 or JWT are more suited for app.

Comment: any idea on which is the better among the Oauth2 or JWT?

Comment: If you add the spring-security-jwt dependency, spring boot will use jwt with oauth2. While using jwt on its own (with jjwt) is possibly more flexible (with what you include in your token) , I would say oauth2 puts your api in a better position to evolve and it also has less custom code as spring boot takes care of a lot of configuration for you.